# How to write 0.5 in assembly language code?

Tags: assembly, fixed-point

How can I convert the floating point "0.5" into a fixed point digit suitable for an assembly code?

Thank you for your answer,

Edit: I am trying to multiply the contents of AX by half, so I wrote IMUL AX,AX,0.5

The assembler refused this and told me "floating-points are not allowed".

All that I want is to divide the contents of AX by two.

Comment: This will depend on what you want to do with it. Assemblers know nothing about fixed point numbers (unless you're trying to use a floating-point extension) so, do what you like.

Comment: Floating-point is implemented by specific instructions on the majority of modern processors. Fixed-point has to be implemented by hand using integer instructions. Especially if you are writing in assembly, you should be using floating-point. And your question lacks enough detail to be answerable anyway.

Comment: Ok, that's a lot different now. Do you want to interpret `AX` as signed or as unsigned?

Comment: I would like to know both the signed and unsigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signed:

```
cwd
sub ax, dx
sar ax, 1
```

Unsigned:

```
shr ax, 1
```